# AngularJS (1.5) dependency injection into models classes (typescript)

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, typescript, model

I am trying to use typescript to build an angularjs (1.5) application.

I want to make the equivalent of a factory that calls a model (which can take parameters).

I could do the following if I were to do it in pure JS

```
angular.module('test', [])
    .factory('Talker', [$q, function($q){
      return Talker()

      function Talker(name) {
        this.name = name || 'Bobuel Johnson'; 
      }
      Talker.prototype.deferredHello = function(){
        $q.when('Hi, I\'m ' + this.name);
      }
    }])
```

Now I want to do this in typescript such that I can have the Talker class but I want to be able to inject (in this case) $q into the model class.

Please, can you help me figure out how to get this set up as the typescript equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a **service** recipe instead of a **factory**, if only to prepare for angular2. A TypeScript rewrite of that js code would look something like this.

```js
class Talker {
  public static $inject = ['$q']; // configure angular di
  private name: string = 'Some talker';  

  constructor(private $q) {}

  public deferredHello() {
    this.$q.when('Hi, I\'m ' + this.name);
  }
}

angular.module('test').service('Talker', Talker);
```

You can find the translation to js [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Talker%20%7B%0D%0A%09public%20static%20%24inject%20%3D%20%5B'%24q'%5D%0D%0A%09private%20name%3A%20string%20%3D%20'Some%20talker'%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor(private%20%24q)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09public%20deferredHello()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.%24q.when('Hi%2C%20I%5C'm%20'%20%2B%20this.name)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aangular.module('test').service('Talker'%2C%20Talker)%3B).

If a **factory** is absolutely needed you should be able to do that as well like this:

```js
class Talker {

  private name: string = 'Some talker';

  constructor(private $q) {}

  public deferredHello() {
    this.$q.when('Hi, I\'m ' + this.name);
  }
}

angular.module('test').service('Talker', function($q) {
  return new Talker($q);
});
```

You can check out the generated javascript [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Talker%20%7B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09private%20name%3A%20string%20%3D%20'Some%20talker'%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor(private%20%24q)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09public%20deferredHello()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.%24q.when('Hi%2C%20I%5C'm%20'%20%2B%20this.name)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aangular.module('test').service('Talker'%2C%20function(%24q)%20%7B%0D%0A%09return%20new%20Talker(%24q)%3B%0D%0A%7D)%3B).

If you need to create multiple instances of **Talker** you can do it this way.

```js
class Talker {

  private name: string = 'Some talker';

  constructor(private $q, money: number) {}

  public deferredHello() {
    this.$q.when('Hi, I\'m ' + this.name);
  }
}

angular.module('test').service('Talker', function($q) {
  // we can ask for more parameters if needed
  return function talkerFactory(money) { // return a factory instead of a new talker

    return new Talker($q, money);
  };

});

angular.module('yatest').service('Organiser', function(Talker) {
  let talker = Talker(42); // will call talkerFactory and return a new instance of talker 
})
```

The example for that is [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Talker%20%7B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09private%20name%3A%20string%20%3D%20'Some%20talker'%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor(private%20%24q%2C%20money%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09public%20deferredHello()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.%24q.when('Hi%2C%20I%5C'm%20'%20%2B%20this.name)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aangular.module('test').service('Talker'%2C%20function(%24q)%20%7B%0D%0A%09return%20function%20talkerFactory(money)%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20return%20a%20factory%20instead%20of%20a%20new%20talker%0D%0A%09%09return%20new%20Talker(%24q%2C%20money)%3B%20%0D%0A%09%7D%20%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aangular.module('yatest').service('Organiser'%2C%20function(Talker)%20%7B%0D%0A%09let%20talker%20%3D%20Talker(42)%3B%20%2F%2F%20will%20call%20talkerFactory%20and%20return%20a%20new%20instance%20of%20talker%20%0D%0A%7D)).

Comment: thanks for your advice! I'm not really sure how I could provide the model as a service since the service is a singleton and I'll require several instances of the model, Moreover the Talker model have problems if I wanted to feed it parameters while instantiating. Do you recommend that I use the factory version that you mentioned or is there a better way?

Comment: there is a pattern for creating multiple instances of something from a service, you can use it, just return a function that when called will return a new instance of the class. I'll add an example for that as well. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2708

Comment: A little late to the party but this answer should be marked as valid!

Comment: @timothy.B thanks for the comment but it's really up to the OP if the answer was a solution to his problem. I hope it helped you.